# Square div with width based on percentage height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do the inverse of this fiddle, make a square with a width based on an a 100% based height.

http://jsfiddle.net/j372H/6/

```
<html  style="height:100%">
<body style="height:100%">
<div id="square" style="background-color:black"></div>
</body>
</html>

$(window).ready(updateWidth);
$(window).resize(updateWidth);

function updateWidth()
{
var square = $('#square');
var size = square.width();

square.css('height',size);
}
```

Thank a lot for your help.

Seb.

Comment: If someone can help me to adapt this code to make a square that fit the 100% height.(the width in px must be equal to the height in %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS set the height of the div also

```
<style>

html,body,#square { height:100%; }

</style>
```

then the reverse for your js function

```
function updateWidth()
{
var square = $('#square');
var size = square.height();

square.css('width',size);
}
```

**Demo courtesy of wared**  - jsfiddle.net/wared/spSLP - - nice one, wared

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).ready(updateHeight);
$(window).resize(updateHeight);

function updateHeight()
{
    var square = $('#square');
    var size = square.height();

    square.css('width',size);
}
```

NOTE - This needs the square div to have a height in the first place - height does not behave the same as width - just a heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple math equation in the variable you can set a square div that re-sizes automatically.
change the 100 after * to give you a % width for your div.
see working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr8gj/506/) for responsive width

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var height =  ( $(window).height() / 100) * 100 ;
  $('#square').width(height);
  $('#square').height(height); 

    });

$(window).resize(function(){

 var height =  ( $(window).height() / 100) * 100 ;
 $('#square').width(height);
 $('#square').height(height); 

    });
```